# How to disable the git pager but just for certain commands?

Tags: git

I like having the pager enabled for `git log` for example, but not `git diff` because I have my own visual diff tool that comes up, and I hate having to hit 'q' at the command line after the diff is done with. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883189/how-can-i-turn-on-a-pager-for-the-output-of-git-status

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can set the `pager.diff` configuration variable to disable the pager for specific subcommands. See `pager.<cmd>` in [*git-config(1)*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

```
git config --global pager.diff false
```

Leave out `--global` if you only want to make this configuration change for the current repository.

Comment: To disable for a particular invocation: `git -c pager.diff=false log ...`.

Comment: @mjs I think an easier way is `git -P diff`. See [-P docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git/2.35.0#Documentation/git.txt--P)

Comment: and likewise, pager.branch works for `git branch`

Answer (score 8):

Just add `| cat` to the end of your `git` call.  This will trick `git` into dumping the whole thing as standard output (because no longer interactive).

e.g.

```
git diff --stat | cat
```

Sadly, you'll lose the color in your output, as a side-effect, but you can force it on by adding `--color` before the `| cat`, yielding:

```
git diff --stat --color | cat
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. It might not be the most systematic way, but some times quick and dirty does it.

Answer (score -1):

Not a great solution, but you could have a git wrapper which determines what command you are running and pipes the output through cat to eliminate the terminal detection.

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in)
  diff) git "$@" | cat;;
  *) exec git "$@";;
esac
```

Of course my example program is entirely braindead.  You would need to skip over options instead of hard-coding "$1" in the program.